# Why evaluating sizeof in a loop isn't faster than using a fixed number for the size of the object?

Tags: c, sizeof

When it comes to writing & reading data (variables and objects) from & to files, our teacher told us to do it like this:

```
while(1){
if(fwrite(&object, sizeof object, 1, fp)!= 1){
break;
}
```

However, it seems rather logical that this should be faster:

```
int num = sizeof object;
while(1){
if(fwrite(&object, num, 1, fp)!=1){
break;
}
```

After all, evaluating the size of the object won't be done every iteration. So, I wrote a simple program to test this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct block{
    int val;
    float mal; //the variables are irrelevant here
    char *ch;
}object;

int main(void){
    FILE *fp;

     int f = sizeof object;

    if((fp=fopen("file.bin", "wb"))==NULL){
        puts("Unable to open file.");
        exit(1);
    }
    int n = 2; //either set n to 1 or 2 
    switch(n){
        case 1: 
        for(int i = 0; i <101; i++){
        if(fwrite(&object, sizeof object, 1, fp)!=1){
            puts("I/O error.");
            break;
        }
        break;
    }
    case 2: 
    for(int i = 0; i <101; i++){
        if(fwrite(&object, f, 1, fp)!=1){
            puts("I/O error.");
            break;
}
break;
}
}
puts("Fin.");
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I ran this program multiple times in devc++, to my surprise there was basically no difference in time passed.
For `n = 1` I got these times: `0.0292`, `0.02757`, `0.02946`, `0.02847`. 
For `n = 2`: `0.03022`, `0.028`, `0.02954`, `0.02885`.
The second option isn't faster and there appears to be no distinguishable pattern. What gives?

Comment: `sizeof` is a compile time concept, not runtime.

Comment: For the examples shown, `sizeof` is a compile-time constant. (If you have `int c = 4; int r = 5; int matrix[r][c];` then `matrix` is a variable length array or VLA, and `sizeof(matrix)` is computed at runtime, in general. Only for a VLA is the `sizeof` a runtime computation.)  Your speed testing is primarily measuring the speed of I/O (slow) and not of stashing values onto the stack for the function calls — it is no surprise you cannot measure any meaningful differences.

Comment: **Both** should compile to the exact same machine code on any sensible compiler given high enough optimization level...

Comment: Even if there *were* a difference in performance, it would be such a small difference that it would typically be rather difficult to detect without very careful measurements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect the intermediate compilation results, you can see how they're essentially equivalent.

Compiling using `gcc` and the `-fdump-tree-optimized` flag produces the following results:

```
$ ls
speedtest.c
$ gcc -fdump-tree-optimized speedtest.c
$ ls
a.out  speedtest.c  speedtest.c.227t.optimized
```

If you take a peek in the `*.optimized` file, you'll find excerpts like:

For `int f = sizeof object;`:

```
f_9 = 16;
```

For `fwrite(&object, sizeof object, 1, fp)`:

```
_1 = fwrite (&object, 16, 1, fp_12);
```

For `fwrite(&object, sizeof object, 1, fp)`, which is utilizing the assignment in the first excerpt:

```
_2 = (long unsigned int) f_9;
_3 = fwrite (&object, _2, 1, fp_12);
```

As you can see, the `sizeof` operator is being evaluated at compile time.

The `sizeof` operator is a [documented part of the C standard](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.5.3.4.html) and is [defined alongside other unary operators, such as `++` and `--`](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.5.3.html).