# Repetitive calculations with sizeof, strlen, etc

Tags: c, compiler-optimization

Let's say I have a large array and I'm doing something like the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]); ++i)
    printf("arr[%d]=%d\n", i, arr[i]);
```

Of course, the `sizeof` stuff shouldn't be calculated every time so it should be like this instead:

```
size_t len = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    printf("arr[%d]=%d\n", i, arr[i]);
```

My questions is whether it can be assumed that any compiler will automatically do the above optimization and so it doesn't matter which approach I use? Or should I assume that that's not the case and the second approach is the only correct one.

Comment: optimisation will depend on the compiler you use. I would have gone with the second approach to be sure.

Comment: `sizeof` and `strlen` are completely different animals here.  `sizeof(type)` or `sizeof(obj)` is a compile time constant, except for VLAs, so `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])` is just seen by the compiler as something like `24/4` and [constant folding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding) on any sane compiler will turn it into the constant `6`.  But `strlen` is a completely different situation.

Comment: @NateEldredge I see, but yes in the above it could be a VLA too.

Comment: Even so, it can't change between iterations so it ought to be [hoisted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-invariant_code_motion) out of the loop.  But in the case of `for (i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)`, the compiler has to wonder whether the loop body might modify the string `s`.  If it can't prove that it does not, which may be hard, then it will have to call `strlen` again on every iteration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c - Why evaluating sizeof in a loop isn't faster than using a fixed number for the size of the object? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50670787/why-evaluating-sizeof-in-a-loop-isnt-faster-than-using-a-fixed-number-for-the-s) (although it appears that this one is better)

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason to hoist the division out of the loop condition.  It isn't even a question of how many times the division is evaluated (as is the usual concern in these cases, and may require the compiler to use "escape analysis" to determine whether the length value can change between iterations).  The simple fact is that `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])` is a constant expression which will be evaluated at compile time, and will be no different to if you hard-coded a number there.

Comment: I see, does that apply to doing `strlen(x)` too, or is `strlen` an entirely different thing?

Comment: `strlen(x)` is very different.  As I mentioned, a compiler might use escape analysis to determine whether the result of that expression can change in each iteration (e.g. if the string `x` points to is modified).  If the optimizer can tell for certain that the result of `strlen(x)` will be the same on every iteration, of course it should evaluate it only once.  But this is far less clear-cut and obvious than the `sizeof` case.